# Mocking static method is not working as expected in java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class

```
public class MyMainClass{
    
    public void mainLogic(){
     handleEvictedKeys( key, value, removalCause)
}

    private void handleEvictedKeys(final Object key, final Object value, final RemovalCause removalCause) {
        if (removalCause.equals(RemovalCause.SIZE)) {
            remote.setOrReplaceValueForKey((String) key, (Map<String, String>) value);
        } else {
            log.warn("Key {} and Value {} was evicted from cache for theme {} for the reason {}", key, value,
                cacheInformation.getThemeName(), removalCause);
        }
    }

        GenericCacheBuilder genericCacheBuilder = CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider
            .getCacheBuilder(cacheInformation.getRemoteCachePreference());
        return (RemoteCacheManager) genericCacheBuilder.buildCacheManager(cacheInformation);
    }
}
```

My remote provider

```
public class CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider {

        private static final ImmutableMap<AllowedCacheSystem, GenericCacheBuilder<?>> CACHE_SYSTEM_TO_CACHE_BUILDER_MAP =
            ImmutableMap.<AllowedCacheSystem, GenericCacheBuilder<?>>builder()
                .put(AllowedLocalCacheSystem.COMMON_CAFFEINE, new CommonCaffeineCacheBuilder())
                .put(AllowedRemoteCacheSystem.COMMON_REDIS, new CommonRedisCacheBuilder())
                .build();
    
    
        public static GenericCacheBuilder getCacheBuilder(AllowedCacheSystem cacheSystem) {
            return CACHE_SYSTEM_TO_CACHE_BUILDER_MAP.get(cacheSystem);
        }
    }
```

When i try to write unit test for MyMainClass

```
public class TestMyMainClass(){


//all dependencies
@InjectMocks
public MyMainClass mtestClass;

public void mymainLogic(){

        cacheSystemToCacheManagerProviderStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider.class);
        cacheSystemToCacheManagerProviderStatic.when(
                CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider::getCacheBuilder)
            .thenReturn(getCacheBuilderMock);
mtestClass.handleEvictedKeys(a,b,c)
}

}
```

I am trying to mock the call CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider.getCacheBuilder() however this is making actual call and trying to create instance of `new CommonCaffeineCacheBuilder()` this pulls lot of dependencies and breaking UT.

How to mock this static call correctly

Comment: The code in the question doesn't compile, or even make any sense (for example, if `getCacheBuilder` is `static`, why is it called on an _instance_ of `cacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider` retrieved from the non-existent `getCacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider` method?) You'll need to provide a working [mre] to get the help you need.

Comment: Although, looking again, the call to `new CommonCaffeineCacheBuilder()` happens in a static initialiser that will execute as soon as the `CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider` class is loaded, before there is an opportunity to mock it. I would recommend refactoring to avoid the use of `static` here, and make `CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider` an interface that can be mocked easily.

Comment: Note that after the edit, this is still not a working example. Please ensure that code you post in your question compiles.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `new CommonCaffeineCacheBuilder()` doesn't happen when the `getCacheBuilder` is executed. It happens before that point, in a static initializer that is executed as soon as the `CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider` class is loaded. This necessarily happens before there is an opportunity to mock it.

A better design would make the `CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider` *substitutable* in `MyMainClass`, allowing it to be mocked more easily:

```java
public class MyMainClass{
    private final CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider cacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider;

    public MyMainClass(CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider cacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider) {
        this.cacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider = cacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider;
    }

    public String myLogic(CacheInformation cacheInformation){
        return getRemoteCacheManager(cacheInformation).getValueForKey("some string");
    }

    public RemoteCacheManager getRemoteCacheManager(CacheInformation cacheInformation) {
        GenericCacheBuilder<?> genericCacheBuilder = cacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider
                .getCacheBuilder(cacheInformation.getRemoteCachePreference());
        return (RemoteCacheManager) genericCacheBuilder.buildCacheManager(cacheInformation);
    }
}
```

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class TestMyMainClass {
    @Test
    public void myLogicTest() {
        var mockCacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider = mock(CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider.class);
        var mockCacheBuilder = mock(GenericCacheBuilder.class);
        var mockCacheManager = mock(RemoteCacheManager.class);
        var mockCacheInformation = mock(CacheInformation.class);

        when(mockCacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider.getCacheBuilder(any())).thenReturn(mockCacheBuilder);
        when(mockCacheBuilder.buildCacheManager(any())).thenReturn(mockCacheManager);
        when(mockCacheManager.getValueForKey("some string")).thenReturn("some value");

        MyMainClass myMainClass = new MyMainClass(mockCacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider);
        assertEquals("some value", myMainClass.myLogic(mockCacheInformation));
    }

}
```

The key is to make `CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider` an *interface*:

```java
public interface CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider {
    GenericCacheBuilder<?> getCacheBuilder(AllowedCacheSystem system);
}
```

With an *implementation* that uses the real cache providers:

```java
public class StandardCacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider implements CacheSystemToCacheManagerProvider {

    private final ImmutableMap<AllowedCacheSystem, GenericCacheBuilder<?>> CACHE_SYSTEM_TO_CACHE_BUILDER_MAP =
            ImmutableMap.<AllowedCacheSystem, GenericCacheBuilder<?>>builder()
                    .put(AllowedLocalCacheSystem.COMMON_CAFFEINE, new CommonCaffeineCacheBuilder())
                    .put(AllowedRemoteCacheSystem.COMMON_REDIS, new CommonRedisCacheBuilder())
                    .build();


    @Override
    public GenericCacheBuilder<?> getCacheBuilder(AllowedCacheSystem cacheSystem) {
        return CACHE_SYSTEM_TO_CACHE_BUILDER_MAP.get(cacheSystem);
    }
}
```

This ensures that the creation of of `CommonCaffeineCacheBuilder` and `CommonRedisCacheBuilder` instances will not happen in the test.

Comment: As an aside, the cast in `(RemoteCacheManager) genericCacheBuilder.buildCacheManager(cacheInformation)` is also a sign of a poor design. Either `buildCacheManager` should be declared to return `RemoteCacheManager`, or `getRemoteCacheManager` should return whatever type `buildCacheManager` returns. As written, it could throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime.